# Select a "tax month" with a non standard month start/end

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheet with data like this:

| Date | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| July 13 | £40 |  |
| July 21 |  | £60 |

etc.

I'd like to add another column "month" which specifies what month the entry was made in. Only problem is I can't use the standard `MONTH()` function because for accounting purposes, the tax month is 16th - 15th. So `July 13` would be considered to be in the `June/July` tax month, while `July 21` would be considered to be in the `July/August` tax month.

I'm assuming I will need to maintain a table of the specific cut off dates like so:

| Month | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jun/July | 16th June | 15th July |

etc.

But I can't work out how to use this as a lookup table to achieve what I want. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 I'm not going to do that. The sheet in question contains people's personal information, and my question contains more than enough information needed to answer.

Comment: question is weak. copy of a sheet with fake example (real data structure + fake values + desired output) will get you the answer faster. saves us time to recreate your sheet based on your question and run some simulations on it to solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work if your date is in A1:

```
=IF(DAY(A1)>15,TEXT(A1,"MMMM")&"/"&TEXT(A1+20,"MMMM"),TEXT(A1-20,"MMMM")&"/"&TEXT(A1,"MMMM"))
```

---

If sort order is important (e.g. in a subsequent pivot table) I would use this:

```
=IF(DAY(A1)>15,TEXT(A1,"MM MMMM")&"/"&TEXT(A1+20,"MMMM"),TEXT(A1-20,"MM MMMM")&"/"&TEXT(A1,"MMMM"))
```

[image]

Another way to specify the sort order is maintaining a separate table with sort order column. It's a completely different approach.

Comment: This is a great solution and it gets me part way there. The only problem with this is that when I put the summaries in a pivot table (which is why I needed the column), they are out of order. Can you think of a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean? To me pivot looks fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV76J.png

Comment: nice approach and easy to adapt to Excel

Comment: @ZygD That's because "June" is alphabetically before "July". But for example, "February" will probably be ordered before "January" (Because F comes before J), but thats the wrong way round.

Comment: @BenWainwright - I have updated the answer with my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(DAY(A2:A)<16, 
 TEXT("1/"&MONTH(A2:A)-1, "mmmm")&"/"&TEXT("1/"&MONTH(A2:A),   "mmmm"), 
 TEXT("1/"&MONTH(A2:A),   "mmmm")&"/"&TEXT("1/"&MONTH(A2:A)+1, "mmmm"))))
```

[image]